# php update json data based on criteria

Tags: php, json

I have a text file with following json data-

```
{"sender":"175","time":15,"message":"office app","response":{"recipient":{"id":"17"},"message":{"text":"Sorry, this message is not understandable to me."}}}
{"sender":"175","time":15,"message":"office app","response":{"recipient":{"id":"17"},"message":{"text":"But I will learn this in next few days."}}}
{"sender":"175","time":15,"message":"update next","response":{"recipient":{"id":"17"},"message":{"text":"this will be updated next."}}}
{"sender":"175","time":15,"message":"office app","response":{"recipient":{"id":"17"},"message":{"text":"Anything else you want to ask me?"}}}
```

I want to update 3rd record based on two criteria:

1. "id":"17"
2. "message":"update next"

Output of 3rd record I want -

```
{"sender":"175","time":15,"message":"office app","response":{"recipient":{"id":"17"},"message":{"text":"Meanwhile, please wait for our representative to get back to you."}}}
```

please help me to update the record with php.

Comment: It would be easier if you make it a valid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to make a valid JSON 
then you have to convert the JSON to an array
then you have to iterate through the array and find which item matches the criteria
and last you change the values.

JSON file content (filename: items.json):

```
 [
   {"sender":"175","time":15,"message":"office app","response":{"recipient":{"id":"17"},"message":{"text":"Sorry, this message is not understandable to me."}}},
   {"sender":"175","time":15,"message":"office app","response":{"recipient":{"id":"17"},"message":{"text":"But I will learn this in next few days."}}},
   {"sender":"175","time":15,"message":"update next","response":{"recipient":{"id":"17"},"message":{"text":"this will be updated next."}}},
   {"sender":"175","time":15,"message":"office app","response":{"recipient":{"id":"17"},"message":{"text":"Anything else you want to ask me?"}}}
 ]
```

an example code is provided below:

```
<?php

    $json = file_get_contents('items.json');
    $json_as_array = json_decode($json, true);

    $found = null;


    foreach ($json_as_array as $key => $item) 
    {
        if(strtolower($item['message']) == "update next" && $item['response']['recipient']['id'] == 17)
        { 
            $found = $key;
        }
    }


    $json_as_array[$found] = ["sender" => 175, "time" => 15, "message" => "office app", "response" => [ "recipient" => ["id" => 17], "message" => ["text" => "Meanwhile, please wait for our representative to get back to you."]]];


    $json_output = json_encode($json_as_array);
    file_put_contents('items.json', $json_output);


    echo "Done!";

?>
```

Comment: How to save json data in proper way. what I realized, a bracket at start & end and a comma was missing after every record. I call a function to save each record. I called the function 4 times to save 4 record. Here how the function create each record.         
        $log = [
            'sender' => $sData['sId'],
            'time' => $sData['sTime'],
            'message' => $sData['sMsg'],
            'response' => $ans
            ];
Following code save the data-        
        file_put_contents('logfile.txt', json_encode($log). PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

Answer (score 0):

i will not write all of the code but the proper way of storing the json , the way i do is

```
file_put_contents('appendData.txt', json_encode($inRadiusPostalCodes) , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

next when you read the file just read the file with

```
file_get_contents();
```

store it in a variable and then json_decode the string and then loop through your array to update record on desired index like

```
if($index == $someindex){......}
```